# Split a string by equal characters

Tags: java, string, split, substring, character

How could I split a string into a number of sub-strings, where each sub-string contains equal trailing characters? Such as:

```
hello -> h, e, ll, o
helel -> h, e, l, e, l
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `hello` becomes `h e ll o`?

Comment: >each sub-string contains equal trailing characters, expecting a cool java streams answer for this

Comment: If there are multiple characters of the same value trailing each other (next to each other in the string) then they become a new string. Hence why the two 'L' s become two separate sub-strings in the second example

Comment: Not the most elegant way, but you might use a regex like [`(?:(.)(\1))|.`](https://regex101.com/r/jUyYb1/1). [Demo](http://rextester.com/XKKZA40378)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Are capture groups allowed in Java lookarounds?  I couldn't seem to get it working.  Maybe you should post an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It does not use a lookaround but a non capturing group for the grouping of `(.)(\1)`

Comment: Again, post some Java code.  I understand what you're trying to say, but getting it working in Java is another story ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not think of a single regex one-liner here, but if you are open to a two step solution, then we can do a regex replacement, followed by a split on space:

```
String input = "hello";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\w)(?!\\1)", "$1 ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split(" ")));
input = "helel";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\w)(?!\\1)", "$1 ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split(" ")));

[h, e, ll, o]
[h, e, l, e, l]
```

### Demo

The trick here is that we add a space separator in front of every character which is *not* immediately followed by the same character.  So the `ll` in `hello` remain adjacent, because the lookahead assertion would fail in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pattern and Matcher like so :

```
String text = "hello";
String regex = "(.)\\1*";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(result);
```

If you are using Java 9+ you can use :

```
String text = "hello";
String regex = "(.)\\1*";
List<String> result = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Outputs

```
[h, e, ll, o]
```